# Attaching jsondata to the call of loading a jsonstore in Extjs via POST request

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, httpwebrequest

is there a way to attach jsondata to a POST request for loading a store?  I know it's possible through a GET request by simply adding **params : {data1 : 1, data2 : 2}** on the load call, but I've had no success attaching jsondata.  I've tried the following and a few variations of it and no luck.  I'm using Extjs 2.2 w/ Alfresco

```
//create store
        var memberStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                url : url/getMembers,
                method : 'POST'
            }),
            fields : ['username'],
            root : 'members'
        });

//function that loads store when it is called
    function getMembers() {

        memberStore.load({
            //params : {action : "getmembers", groupname : "GROUP_Test"}
            jsonData : {
                action : "getmembers",
                groupname : "GROUP_Test"    
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling a store.load(), I created a function that would run an ajax request for the data.  On a successfull callback, I would then load the store.  Below is my code.

```
//create store
var memberStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields : ['username'],
        root : 'members'
    });

//function that loads store when it is called 
function getMembers() {

    var parameters = {
       node : dynamicNodeId  
    }

    Ext.Ajax.Request({
      url : 'url/getMembers',
      method : 'POST',
      jsonData : Ext.encode(parameters),
      success : function(response, opts) {
        //decode json string
        var responseData = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

        //Load store from here
        memberStore.loadData(responseData);
      }
  }); 

}//eo getMembers
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way.

```
Ext.apply(store.baseParams, { param1: '1', param2: '2'});       
Ext.apply(store.proxy.conn, { jsonData: { data1: 'data1', data2: 'data2'} });
store.load();
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor for `**HttpProxy**` takes a connection object. And Connection object understands `**jsonData**`. So you can do this:

```
//create store
        var memberStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                url : url/getMembers,
                method : 'POST',
                //here is the change
                jsonData: {data1 : 1, data2 : 2}
            }),
            fields : ['username'],
            root : 'members'
        });

//function that loads store when it is called
    function getMembers() {

        memberStore.load({
            //params : {action : "getmembers", groupname : "GROUP_Test"}
            jsonData : {
                action : "getmembers",
                groupname : "GROUP_Test"    
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use baseParams: { key: "value", key2: "value2" }

This should work with the store using both GET and POST.

Comment: Hi Juan,

Sorry for such a late reply.  Unfortunately, baseParams would not work for me as the params would change.  What I ended up doing was just create running an Ajax Request ( Ext.Ajax.Request({}) ) and load the store on a success return.

Comment: Oh, I see.. That was an important detail.. 
Glad you found a solution :)

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks again for your reply, as requested, I've posted my solution.  Cheers!